# Leaflet: Custom bin legend for raster

Tags: r, colors, leaflet, legend

I've been playing around with the `leaflet` package and can't create a proper legend for a raster.

The problem is as follows: I've created an informative map with this code:

raster file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7mw858dxh5MODZqSHNHbFR3clU

```
library(raster)
library(leaflet)
r <- raster('raster.tif')
colores <- c('red', 'green', 'blue', 'chocolate', 'deeppink', 'grey')
at <- seq(0, 4800, 800)
cb <- colorBin(palette = colores, bins = length(at), domain = at)

leaflet() %>% 
    setView(-67.5,-16, zoom = 7) %>%
    addRasterImage(r, colors = cb) %>%
    addLegend(pal = cb, values = at)
```

Variable `r` is a raster with precipitation data ranging from 171 to 4667 mm/year.

Output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycYEi.jpg

I want to get a legend with 6 bins using the colors passed to the variable `colores` but the output shows 10 bins ignoring the ranges I passed to the `at` variable.

How should I achieve what I want?

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @TimSalabim Added raster file and output. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to replace `length(at)` with `at` in your `colorBin` call

```
library(raster)
library(leaflet)
r <- raster('raster.tif')
colores <- c('red', 'green', 'blue', 'chocolate', 'deeppink', 'grey')
at <- seq(0, 4800, 800)
cb <- colorBin(palette = colores, bins = at, domain = at)

leaflet() %>% 
    setView(-67.5,-16, zoom = 7) %>%
    addRasterImage(r, colors = cb) %>%
    addLegend(pal = cb, values = at)
```